Какие знаки препинания нужны во фразе "настроение осень"?
Какие знаки препинания нужны во фразе "настроение осень"?

"Настроение осень" аналогично "ситуация SOS". Тире в песне не ставят:
Я сошла с ума,
Я сошла c ума,
Мне нужна она,
Мне нужна она,
Мне нужна она...

Я сошла с ума-а...

Меня полностью нет
Абсолютно всерьёз,
Ситуация HELP,
Ситуация SOS.

Тире можно ставить, если можно воткнуть указательное "это".
Например:
Цель - Эверест!
Цель - это Эверест!

Примеры из нацкорпуса


Евгений Сухов. Делу конец ― сроку начало (2007)  Ольга, откинувшись на спинку, нервно курила. Настроение — дрянь.

Людмила Гурченко. Аплодисменты (1994-2003)  А снимаем последние кадры картины. Настроение — бодрячок.

Юлий Даниэль. Письма из заключения (1966-1970)  Не пишется. Настроение — гроб. Хоть бы скорее письма были.



PS "Время ночь" может быть сокращено просто до номинативного "Ночь". Поэтому там тире не ставят.

А зачем сходить с ума?  И причем тут осеннее настроение? Я вам "предсказала"  правильное написание "Настроение осень" в названии и в тексте, но это вас почему-то очень расстроило)  Приведите, пожалуйста, ПРАВИЛО, по которому отсутствует тире, которое должна стоять по Розенталю. Или мы в нашей реальности давно уже живем без правил?)

"Ситуация СОС" -редакторы тире не поставили, у них и спрашивайте. "Настроение осень" аналогично.

В названии допустимо, но в тексте стоит тире. Настроение – осень.  И никаких номинаций в названии я не вижу. Мы же эту тему обсуждаем. Давайте не будем отклоняться и сокращать. Мне нужны правила, грамматика и анализ, если это лингвистический форум русского языка, а не чат для разговоров, ага?

Я не отклоняюсь, а привожу вам аналогию, где правило Розенталя не работает. У редакторов "Ситуация СОС" без тире.

А не надо сравнивать несравнимое. Ситуация СОС построена по образцу приложение + определяемое слово. Это грамматика. В художественном тексте такое сочетание будет метафорическим, если используется в названии. Произношение без паузы. Но зачем сохранять худ. номинатив в тексте, это объясните. Там как раз пауза нужна. Давайте будем точными в своих решениях. Почему у вас одна номинативная форма идет как единственно верная? Интересно, что встречается запись с прописной буквы: Настроение Осень. Это выглядит как название настроения (имя собств.).

Не поверите, но Ваш случай - точная копия происшествия с названием повести Людмилы Петрушевской "Время ночь".

Как с ним мучались, переводя на другие языки, особенно тире пытались впихнуть. Она приняла только американское "Время: ночь", но не желала никаких знаков.

Ответ исправлен
Правильно: Настроение — осень.
Пояснение

Смысл: Настроение осеннее. Это характеристика подлежащего, основной вариант для текста. Пауза обозначена тире, два ударения (на подлежащем и сказуемом).

Двоеточие не подойдет ни по графике, ни по интонации. Интонационно — это подчеркнутая пауза при неполном понижении (интонационное
предупреждении о дальнейшем пояснении темы). Тире же (в  пределах короткой  фразы) не предупреждает о пояснении, а сразу дает характеристику.


Настроение: осеннее. Предложение выглядит как перечень ответов, что маловероятно. Надо смотреть по контексту.
ПРАВИЛО. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым по Розенталю, пункт 1
1. Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии 
связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены 
существительными в форме именительного падежа: Одиночество в 
творчестве — тяжёлая штука (Ч.); 

ОКОНЧАТЕЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ:
(1)Тире в двусоставном предложении в тексте.
(2) Отсутствие знака в номинативном сочетании слов. Тогда это или название текста, или номинативное предложение в составе текста, что маловероятно, хотя и возможно.
ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ (дополнительный материал)

Можно ли вообще не ставить знак по аналогии с названием книги: ВрЕмя ночь. Думаю, что такой вариант возможен именно в названиях, но не в тексте.

Смысл такой записи как в предложении: ВрЕмя как ночь.   То есть это время, которое можно назвать ночью.


При постановке тире мы получили бы: Время — ночь, то есть  прямое значение слов, а не характеристику  в переносном значении. Поэтому автор не соглашался на тире.

В заданном предложении мы получим такой же смысл: настроение, которое можно назвать осенью. А это  по грамматике номинативное сочетание настроение осень, приложение + определяемое слово. Для названия подходит.

Примечание
Об "американском" двоеточии.  Русский язык вообще загадка для носителей английского языка, как и интонационное выделение слов (логическое ударение).  Время (какое именно?): ночь. Это им понятнее. Но у них графика другая (прописная буква).
The Time: Night (Russian: Время ночь) is a novella by Russian author Lyudmila Petrushevskaya.

Итак, в предыдущем ответе у меня было сказано, что в названиях можно писать "Настроение осень", а в тексте следует поставить тире: Настроение — осень.
Настроение действительно осеннее, поэтому послушаем эту песню: Марсель — Настроение осень
А это из текста песни:
Настроение — Осень,
Я закрываю глаза и прибавляю громкость…
Если кто меня спросит, отвечу:
«Я живой, настроение — Осень».
Настроение — Осень,
Я закрываю глаза и прибавляю громкость…
Если кто меня спросит, отвечу:
«Я живой, настроение — Осень».

Да, всё именно так: в названии тире нет, но оно есть в тексте: Настроение — осень.
